# Powershell script to delete emails from mailbox older than an 7 month or specified dates

Tags: powershell, exchange

I have problem with converting my `Search-Mailbox` command to another one. If you all know in the future as `Search-Mailbox` is retired. So I need to use another cmdlet for this command.

My working right now command with `Search-Mailbox`

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity test@test.comm -SearchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))" -deletecontet
```

I read a lot of times https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/ediscovery/delete-messages?view=exchserver-2019#step-2-delete-the-message and try do step by step and get this code.

```
New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove older than 7 month messages" -ExchangeLocation test@test.com -ContentMatchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))"

Start-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Remove older than 7 month messages"

New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Remove older than 7 month messages" -Purge -PurgeType SoftDelete
```

But its not work for me. getting error

```
Unable to execute the task. Reason: The search "Remove older than 8 month messages" is still running or it didn't

return any results. Please wait until the search finishes or edit the query and run the search again.
```

ADD my full PowerShell script

```
Start-Transcript


$smtpServer="smtp.office365.com" # Office 365 official smtp server 
$from = "IT Support <test@test.com>" # email from  
$logging = "Enabled" # Set to Disabled to Disable Logging 
$testing = "Disabled" # Set to Disabled to Email Users 
$testRecipient = "test@test.com"  
$date = Get-Date -format ddMMyyyy 

$Username = "test@test.com"
$Password = "test-" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri  https://eur04b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com/powershell-liveid?PSVersion=5.1.17763.1007 -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection

 Import-PSSession $Session

Get-ComplianceSearchAction
New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove older than 7 month messages" -ExchangeLocation test@test.com  -ContentMatchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))"
Start-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Remove older than 7 month messages"
New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Remove older than 7 month messages" -Purge -PurgeType SoftDelete
```

Comment: Have you tried to `wait until the search finishes or edit the query and run the search again`?

Comment: im using script, it allways finishing search and asking then ```Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
This operation will make message items meeting the criteria of the compliance search "Remove older than 7 month
messages" completely inaccessible to users. There is no automatic method to undo the removal of these message items.``` then i press Y or A i will get what error

Comment: Did you run `Get-ComplianceSearchAction` to check for already running searches?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes i try it. i will post my all powershell script for to make my question more clearly

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use a retention policy to do this?

Comment: @joeqwerty i try it with with RetentionPolicy, i add it and dont delete anything

Comment: It can take up to 7 days to be applied. If you want to force it, follow this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/set-up-an-archive-and-deletion-policy-for-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide#optional-step-5-run-the-managed-folder-assistant-to-apply-the-new-settings

Comment: i try this one, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
New-ComplianceSearch -Name "Remove older than 7 month messages" -ExchangeLocation test@test.com -ContentMatchQuery "(Received >= 01/12/2017 -and Received <= $((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))"
```

Comment: still dont remove anything

Comment: @mausasu1234 Which emails do you want to delete? Based on the command you post above, the date range is from 01/12/2017 to the current date(Minus 7 months).

Comment: @mausasu1234 Hi, i'm here to confirm if the compliance search issue has been fixed, if the above replies are helpful to you, you could mark the best answer. Have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 0):

I tested the compliance search in my lab environment,and I found that the search action(**ComplianceSearchAction**) couldn't be assigned to the search(**ComplianceSearch**) before the compliance search completed.

The following snapshot is my test result(After the status of the compliance search was changed from "**Starting**" to "**Completed**", the search action could be assigned to the search):
[image]

Therefore, if you create a compliance search and assign search action to it immediately(Use scripts to run these commands simultaneously), the "**New-ComplianceSearchAction**" command may not work.

Comment: thank you, now then i using first ```New-ComplianceSearch``` then  ```Get-ComplianceSearchAction``` i dont getting error, but then i press Y or A my window close very fast, but dont delete anything of emails.

Comment: @Iwan_Wang your email have been deleted?

Comment: @mausasu1234 It didn't delete my emails, however, I tried to modify the "-ContentMatchQuery" parameter with a subject keyword, it worked. Based on the test result, it seems that the value of this parameter in the above command is inproper.

Comment: @Iwan_Wang maybe do you know how to change it ? it seems getting date -7 mouth, but why didn't work i really don't understand

Comment: @mausasu1234 You could try the following command in my new reply. Hope it's helpful to you.